# Ruby case switch statement, execute every case

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I'm no Ruby guru so please can I get some help: I want to add whatever code is needed so that there is an option where the following case statement will execute every case. Basically if the user declares a 'browser' name at command line then Cucumber selenium tests will be run against a certain platform/browser. I want it so that if they declare 'all',  or if they declare nothing (else) then every case will be executed.

Thanks

```
case ENV['BROWSER']
  when 'safari'
    $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :safari
    $browser_name = 'Safari'
  when 'mobile'
    $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    $browser_name = 'Mobile'
    $browser.manage.window.resize_to(400, 650)
   else
   $browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
   $browser_name = 'Chrome'
end
```

Comment: In Ruby `$`-prefixed variables like `$browser` are global and these are almost always trouble, so they're best avoided.

Answer (score 3):

If you need that sort of thing, a `case` statement is only part of the solution. You need to iterate as well. Break it out a little differently:

```
BROWSERS = %w[ safari chrome mobile ]
BROWSER_ALIASES = {
  all: BROWSERS
}

# Interpret the environment variable as either an alias, or a single
# step to run.
browsers = BROWSER_ALIASES[ENV['BROWSER']] || [ ENV['BROWSER'] ]

browsers.each do |browser|
  case (browser)
  when 'safari'
    # ... Safari specific action
  when 'mobile'
    # ...
  end
end
```

This expansion allows you to trigger zero, one or many of the browsers, plus set up arbitrary aliases as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give this a go and see where i end up @tadman

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a switch then. The purpose of a switch statement is to NOT run every other case (it's designed to be exclusive). Just use `if` statements instead.

There are actually several ways to set up the `if`s but if you want to keep it looking kind of like a switch, this is probably your best bet:

```
if ENV['BROWSER'] == 'safari' || ENV['BROWSER'] == 'all'
  # do safari stuff
end
if ENV['BROWSER'] == 'mobile' || ENV['BROWSER'] == 'all'
  # do mobile stuff
end
if ENV['BROWSER'] == 'chrome' || ENV['BROWSER'] == 'all'
  # do chrome stuff
end
```

Comment: This looks straight forward, though i'm wondering, if the user opts for the 'all' option as declared here, will all browsers be executed concurrently or consecutively?

Comment: @user1738702 consecutively. Unless you're somehow running it in a thread environment. A single threaded program will have to wait for whatever it's currently working on to end before it starts on the next bit.